# Prove that the discrete time function $\cos(\frac{\pi}{8}\cdot n^2)$ is periodic.

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

How can I formally determine the period of the following discrete-time function?

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{8}\cdot n^2)$

It's difficult for me to approach this since it is a special property of working in discrete time. I.e. if this function was considered in continuous time then it is not periodic since it's period is constantly changing.

I have noticed that the set of squared numbers are in the pattern {odd, even, odd, even, ... } and I know that $\cos(\pi\times odd) = -1$. Then I get stuck.

I tried using Euler's definition for cos:

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$

But I haven't gotten anywhere with that. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Hint: $(n+8)^2 - n^2 = 16(n + 4)$.

Comment: @dxiv I've been working on it since you posted your comment. I'd like to confirm, you are hinting at me getting this to a form where I have just $\pi*n^2$ correct?

Comment: What I am hinting at is that $\frac{\pi}{8} \cdot n^2$ and $\frac{\pi}{8} \cdot (n+8)^2$ differ by a multiple of $2 \pi$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @dxiv I got it. Well, you gave me the answer. Thanks for the help though!